# Server-side print to PDF of HTML file in /tmp?

Tags: ubuntu, php, firefox, pdf, xvfb

I'm working on a project where we need consistent printing of certain pages, and PDFs are made for that. The customers also like to have some local copies, so this would be a two-fold win. Things get really precarious in printing as far as where page breaks end up and how padding effects things.

**What I want to do:**

1. User is viewing a page
2. User requests a PDF
3. PHP generates a HTML file, pretty much the site minus the wrapper and plus CSS
4. PHP stores that to /tmp/foobar.html
5. PHP executes a command that prints to PDF, similar to `firefox --display=:1 -print /tmp/foobar.html -printmode pdf -printfile /tmp/foobar.pdf`
6. PHP uploads that PDF to Amazon S3 for permanent storage, adds into our database for future reference

**What I've tried:**

I've installed Firefox on my server and Xvfb. I've tried setting up Xvfb to be a virtual display and have Firefox run on it, but I get `Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1".` no matter what I do. It's probably misconfigured, I did try adding that extension when starting the new screen with no luck. I'm not sure if I'm not going about this the right way. If Firefox and Xvfb are the right route, what's the proper way to get them to talk to eachother? Are there more dependencies? I'll elaborate on this if it turns out to be the right path.

**What I don't want to do:**

No native PHP converters - Lots of nested tables in this HTML, lots of floats, lots of stuff native PHP doesn't handle well. I've tried all 3 already.

I could so easily do this on a Windows server, but I'd rather keep costs down. Plus then I'd have to set up cross-server communications, which will slow things down a bit

TL:DR; I'm trying to print to PDF using Firefox running on a server with no display so I can have a consistent print experience. I've tried Xvfb and I've almost given up. If this is the correct way, how do I configure Xvfb? Otherwise, how else would I go about doing this?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176476/how-can-i-automate-html-to-pdf-conversions . I would go with htmldoc. Never failed me.

Comment: I mentioned at the end of my post that I've tried that and it botched the display. If only it was that easy! Prince in that post looks good, but for the price..

Comment: My **personal** solution so far has been running `wkhtmltopdf.exe` in Wine. Not really fit for a server, but WebKit-based... YMMV (linux version of `wkhtmltopdf` crashed for me)

Answer (score 0):

Use a headless renderer like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) or [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/).

Comment: I'll give wkhtmltopdf a shot and see how it handles our markup. Call me stubborn, but I really like the idea of having the same browser doing the printing as I'm working with. Just would simplify my process a good bit. I suppose wkhtmltopdf shouldn't be much different than Chrome, though.. which sucks, because Chrome doesn't do as well with CSS page break rules as Firefox does.